# Setting up PPPoE wired connection in Ubuntu 18.04.1 Bionic Beaver (Desktop Version)

Tags: networking, netplan

My ISP provides PPPoE connection with username, password and service name and binds my MAC Address. Since I have connected my router to the WAN, the MAC Address of the router has been bound in their server by them. The IP address, Gateway and DNS addresses are automatically obtained.  My Desktop has been connected to the router and the network is working fine.

However, for the purpose of troubleshooting the network when it goes down, I need to connect directly to the computer. Therefore, I need to know how to configure a wired PPPoE connection directly in my computer. The network settings GUI does not allow setting up one.

Please guide me how to -

1) configure a PPPoE connection
2) specify the username, password and service name, and
3) clone my router's MAC address to my desktop

to be able to connect to the internet.

Using "nmcli" command, I am not able to specify a cloned MAC address.

After referring to various community posts, I tried the following command:

nmcli connection add con-name "..." type pppoe username ... password ... service ... parent .... autoconnect no ifname "*" save yes

The pppoe connection gets created but vanishes from the "Settings -> Network" GUI under "Wired" category after some time. Also, neither the command nor the GUI, allows me to specify a cloned MAC address.

It would have been better if there was a GUI for this.

Looking forward to the HELP, as I am not quite conversant with Linux commands.